# why readLine() works, and readUTF() always throws IOException

Tags: java

I send a post request to an address, and this address will return a xml format data back.

I can print out the data by`readLine(),` but when i use `readUTF(),` it always throws `IOException`. below is the code

```
DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(urlCon.getInputStream());
String inputLine = "";

if((inputLine = input.readUTF()) != null) {
    System.out.println(inputLine.toString());
}
input.close();
```

why readUTF() does not work? is it because the data is xml format?

Comment: Can you add stacktrace for exception?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're reading lines, use `readLine()`. Data to be read with `readUTF()` must have been written with `writeUTF().` See the Javadoc.

NB `readUTF()` doesn't return null, so testing for it is futile.